# Compiler gives an error when trying to define class with inheritance

Tags: c++, class, oop, googletest

I'm mildly baffled by an error I get from the compiler. I'm trying to write tests with the GoogleTest Framework. However, in one of my `.h` files where I define classes I get an error.

I have the following code in which the error occurs and I cannot explain why that happens so I hope that someone here can.

```cpp
//Foo.h

#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include "gtest/gtest.h"

class FooTest1: public ::testing::Test
{
// compiler does not complain here
//...
}

//...

class FooTest2: public ::testing::TestWithParam
{
// compiler tells me this is wrong
//...
}
```

This is the error that I get:

> error: expected class-name before '{' token

Is there something I'm missing with `TestWithParam` that won't let me define the class like this?

Comment: Missing semicolons after `}`, although I don't think that is the main issue here.

Comment: Missing semicolons after your class bodies

Comment: Voted to close for typo.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I rewrote instead of copying and forgot the semicolons, but thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TestWithParam` is a class template expecting the type of the test's parameter as template argument, see [the documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#how-to-write-value-parameterized-tests).

e.g.:

```
class FooTest2: public ::testing::TestWithParam<int> {
    //...
};
```

The compiler is complaining because a class template is not a (class) type, only its specializations (e.g. `::testing::TestWithParam<int>`) are (class) types. A class cannot derive from a class template, only from a class type.